# How to solve "Bad CFBundleExecutable" validation error with app store and CocoaPods framework

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, app-store-connect, mac-app-store

I'm having several tricky problems with getting my Mac app with CocoaPods to pass validation into the Mac App Store. It works fine running locally but when I validate, it fails with these errors:

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
Bad Bundle Executable. You must include a valid CFBundleExecutable key in the nested bundle Pods_MSVAPI_macOS [...<stuff>…Contents/Frameworks/MSVAPI.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Pods_MSVAPI_macOS.framework] property list file.

App Store Connect Operation Error
Bad CFBundleExecutable. Cannot find executable file that matches the value of CFBundleExecutable in the nested bundle Pods_MSVAPI_macOS [...<stuff>…Contents/Frameworks/MSVAPI.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/Pods_MSVAPI_macOS.framework] property list file.
```

(MSVAPI.framework is my own framework that my app uses, which I intend to be cross-platform)

I read this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleexecutable and it says "For a framework, it's the shared library framework and must have the same name as the framework but without the .framework extension.". So I tried putting "Pods_MSVAPI_macOS" which is the framework name without the .framework in the "Executable" info entry. No luck.

My next attempt to fix this was to remove the target of Pods_MSVAPI_macos because that's not the actual framework - I have two CocoaPods that I'm using, each which creates its own framework bundle. That worked for getting through validation. But when I came to distribute the app, which I tried locally, it crashed with a "resource not found":

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/<podname>.framework/Versions/A/<podname>
  Referenced from: /Applications/<appname>.app/Contents/Frameworks/MSVAPI.framework/Versions/A/MSVAPI
  Reason: image not found
```

If I try to add the frameworks directly they are greyed out so it appears that they aren't actually being built independently:

[image]

How can I make sure that this CocoaPod's framework (and presumably the other one) gets included in the app bundle, and allow MSVAPI.framework to use it?

Alternatively, how can I get past the CFBundleExecutable validation error at the beginning of my question?

Thanks!